# Accessing HTML Popup in Layer Properties using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, html-popup

Is it possible to access HTML Popups (found in layer properties) programmatically in ArcGIS Desktop 10.2?

I can't find any reference but thought I'd ask to double check.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any way to do this.

If you would like to post an [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com) to have this implemented, then it is certainly one that I would vote for.

---

The asker posted their ArcGIS Idea as [Programmatically access HTML Popup in Layer Properties](https://community.esri.com/ideas/9785).